# add global setting to datatables yajrabox laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I use yajrabox data tables and I want to add the public option to all tables
This plugin needs to select a selector or table. How can I fine-tune my preferences without choosing it

my basic code is

```
$(function() {
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            oLanguage: {
                sProcessing: "<div class='fa-3x'><i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin'></i></div>"
            },
            ajax: '{!! route('show_user_list.data') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'user_type.type_name', name: 'user_type.type_name' },
                { data: 'user_gender.gender_name', name: 'user_gender.gender_name' },
                { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                { data: 'family', name: 'family' },
                { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                { data: 'national_code', name: 'national_code' },
                { data: 'mobile_number', name: 'mobile_number' },
                { data: 'birth_date', name: 'birth_date' },
                @can('user-detail')
                { data: function($user) { return '<a href="/admin/user/detail/' + $user['id'] + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon-anim btn-square"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></a>' }, name: 'view', sortable: false },
                @endcan
            ]
        });
    });
```

and i want use this code without $('#users-table') selector

I need a code like that

```
object.DataTable({
        oLanguage: {
            sProcessing: "<div class='fa-3x'><i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin'></i></div>"
        },

    });
```

this code is example and the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but please try this

```
(function ($, DataTable) {

$.extend(true, DataTable.defaults, {
    oLanguage:{                        
    sProcessing: "<div class='fa-3x'><i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin'></i></div>"          

    }
});
```

})(jQuery, jQuery.fn.dataTable);

Answer (score 0):

this code add object globall

$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {

```
    oLanguage: {
        sProcessing: "<div class='fa-3x'><i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin'></i></div>"
    },
} );
```